# How can we change existing managed package field to unique?

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, appexchange, unique-field, upgrade

We have couple of fields across few objects need to be made unique. These have been released a while ago, and we need to modify them to become unique. But when we try to change the Unique - Do not allow duplicate values checkbox, it's disabled.

[image]

Any help with this please. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think reason this is not allowed is because if some users of your managed package has duplicate data in this field that data can be lost.

Comment: So I think solution can be to create a new field which will be unique and deprecate the existing field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components of Managed Packages are not editable.

You won't be able to modify the properties of fields of manage package object in this case.